# Chosen Select : Update multiple chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to get multiple chosen select display another chosen selected value, for example, I have a company and if a user choose that it's the same company for all mails to be sent, the value selected in the company should be on all other select chosen having class "liv_ent".

Now, it works only for the first select chosen with that class, not all others. I tried updating it once without a loop, and even now with a loop, nothing changes.

Code trigered on when the Toggle is on True (means same company for all mails) :

```
$('.liv_ent').each(function(i, obj) {
       $(this).val($("select[id='liv_ent_val'] option:selected").val()).trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Which is the exact same code called when chosen value changes :

```
$('#liv_ent_val').chosen().change(function () {
            if ($('#liv_exped').prop('checked') == true){
                $('.liv_ent').each(function(i, obj) {
                    $(this).val($("select[id='liv_ent_val'] option:selected").val()).trigger("chosen:updated");
                });
            }
        });
```

What I don't really get, is that even with console.log for the loop, it shows that the loop is getting the right select chosen boxes, but only updates the first !

Edit :
The chosen selects to be updated are dynamically created when a user changes an input number field, for exemple, when he puts 10 in an input, this code triggers :

```
$("#liv_nbr").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var $repeatDiv = $("#repeatDiv");

            $(".newLiv").remove();
            for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
                $repeatDiv.after($repeatDiv.clone().attr("class", "newLiv"));
            }
        });
```

Which creats 9 times more (1 original + 9) the chosen select. The problem is that only the original one gets updated.

Comment: So if you choose an option in one "select" element, you want to choose the same option in other select elements too? Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: Yes. For Html its a simple copy pasted chosen select with same class.

Comment: Is this something you expect? https://jsfiddle.net/7p8nr4qm/2/. If you change an option in the first select drop down, then the remaning select elements will have the same option selected.

Comment: Exactly, but with chosen select

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VoQzJj. Check this. If you change the first select option, it will set others to the same option.

Comment: @MuraliNepalli your code works when selects are natovely on DOM and not created dynamically